# adding a push button on LED string lights

Tags: led

im looking at making a flower in a glass dome with string LED light for a present. the problem is most stings had a on/off switch. Is there a way to attach a push button on/off to it and not have to use a switch. the button will just be easier to put into the base and make it look nice.

project is like this
[https://www.amazon.com/Life-Sized-Enchanted-Inspired-MagicPrincessWhitney-Princess/dp/B01MQK1JXO/ref=sr_1_7?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1543693446&sr=1-7&keywords=rose+flower+dome](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MQK1JXO)

lights used are similar to this
[https://www.amazon.com/Betus-Feet-Fairy-String-Lights/dp/B07HNJGCP7/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1543692887&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=led+string+lights+push+button&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07HNJGCP7)

wanting to add a switch like this
[https://www.amazon.com/HONBAY-1-2inch-Thread-Latching-Button/dp/B01ESEEXXS/ref=sr_1_3?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1543693590&sr=1-3&keywords=on+off+button](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ESEEXXS)

Comment: What's wrong with the latching pushbutton you linked at the bottom of your question? Seems like it fits your goal.

Answer (score 0):

yes, that button will work with those lamps.

Just cut one of the wires between the batteries and the LEDs and connect each end end to a different terminal on the button. soldering is probably the best way to make that connection.

You will nee noth switches to be on at the same to light the LEDs, so maybe turn the battery box switch on and then glue it so that it does not turn off accidentally.

Comment: thank you so much. that is what i was thinking but i wanted to ask someone with more experience. most strands have more than two wires, does it matter which wire i cut?